# Yes/No table, Match and Reverse Index

Tags: vba, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a table filled with Yes and No values. I need a formula that will locate all cells with "Yes" value and index the row (Apples, Orange, Pear) and column (Molly, Joe, Sarah) headers used to define the cell.

Then take the defined row and column information and put it into two columns on a second worksheet.

I would like something that would be able to update if the Yes or No values changed.

My Yes/No Table on worksheet 1:

```
         Molly    Joe    Sarah
Apples    Y       N      Y
Orange    N       Y      N
Pear      Y       N      N
```

What I want it to look like on worksheet 2:

```
Column A   Column B
Molly      Apples
Molly      Pear
Joe        Orange
Sarah      Apple
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to “unpivot” or “reverse pivot” in Excel?](https://superuser.com/q/78439/52365)

Comment: Alternatively, [Unpivot columns (Power Query)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)

Comment: Thank you for showing me the "reverse pivot" feature. It works well. Will it be able to change as the data in my Y/N table changes or will I have to run it every time?

Answer (score 1):

1. Start the Pivot Table Wizard. (Keyboard shortcut: ALT+D, P on Excel 2007) For "Where is the data that you want to analyze?" Select "Multiple Consolidation Ranges PivotTable." Then click Next.

   [image]
2. For "How many page fields do you want?" Select "I will create my own page fields".

   [image]
3. Select your data. Click Next.

   [image]
4. Double click on the grand total value - the one at the intersection of Row Grand and Column Grand, all the way on the lower right hand corner of your pivot table.

   [image]
5. View results.
   [image]

This answer just expands upon the answer noted above here given by DaveParillo at [How to “unpivot” or “reverse pivot” in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

With powerquery (Get and Transfom Data tab Excel 2016, 2013 Powerquery tab after installing free Powerquery [add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39379) from microsoft), using data from table where table name is Table2

**M code:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Molly", type text}, {"Joe", type text}, {"Sarah", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Columns", each ([Value] = "Y")),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute", "Column1", "Value"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Value"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Attribute", "Column A"}, {"Column1", "Column B"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Input:**

[image: Input]

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Process:**

[image: Process]

Comment: did you give this a try?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Replace What:="Y", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole
        For Each cell in .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
           sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cell.End(xlUp).Value
           sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cell.End(xlToLeft).Value
        Next
        .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="Y", LookAt:=xlWhole
    End With 
End Sub
```